# Як перекласти SPOILER, коли йдеться про фільм чи книгу?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Власне, інші значення теж цікаві для перекладу, а їх у слова **spoiler** багато. Мені здається найцікавішим значення повідомлення, яке руйнує інтригу твору.

Значення слова за Оксфордом:

> A description of an important plot development in a television show,
>   film, or book which if previously known may reduce surprise or
>   suspense for a first-time viewer or reader.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoiler)

Словник Мультитран дає таке значення, не маючи вираження одним чи двома словами (переклад мій):

> текст, що видає забагато з сюжету твору для тих, хто його не читав і не бачив.

Ненормативні переклади (рос.):

> вредилка, портилка

[Мультитран](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=spoiler&l1=1)

Чи можемо ми знайти український відповідник до spoiler?

Comment: https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/spoiler цей сайт знаєте?

Comment: Перепрошую, а як перекладається те, що переклав словник Мультитран?

Comment: @bytebuster навіть не уявляла, але завдяки першому коменту тепер знаю, що можна перекласти як "псувака", чому б ні, цікаве слово, дякую

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, ні, не це. Словник Мультитран, наскільки я розумію, перекладає з англійської на російську. Не всі з нас знають російську, тому такий переклад несе мало змісту. Уявіть, що хтось запитує про переклад з англійської і в якості пояснення наводить переклад з англійської на монгольську.

Comment: spoil - псувати, spoiler - те, що псує, відповідно чому б не "псувака", хоча звучить досить дивно:)

Comment: @bytebuster гаразд, зараз виправлю, щоб це не виглядало як монгольська. цитату з оксфорда можна лишити мовою оригіналу?

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна так, у нас на сайті дозволені англійська (як мова самого сайту) і українська (як мова, якою цікавляться). Решту мов можуть не розуміти, тому перекладаємо.

Comment: Щодо сайту slovotvir зазначу, що варіанти, які там пропонують, часто зовсім ненейтральні/непоширені. Тобто варіанти там трапляються дуже цікаві — але в загальному випадку до них треба підходити розмірковано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/spoiler) дається дуже хороший варіант "розцікавник", адже спойлер - це "інформація про книгу, фільм, музичний альбом тощо, яка розкриває сюжет ще до особистого ознайомлення з предметом уваги і тому може зіпсувати враження від твору", отож, як мені здається це слово буде хорошим українським відповідником.